# jQuery autocomplete only works one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQueryUI autocomplete plugin and it works fine but it only works the first time. If the user clicks somewhere else and then tries to use it again it doesn't show up. 
This is my code :

```
$(function() {
    var availableTutorials = [
        "Accounting Department",
        "Administrative",
        "Business Development",
        "Central Services",
        "Corporate Development",
        "Customer Service",
    ];

    $("#TextBox1").autocomplete({
        minChars: 0,
        delay: 0,
        source: availableTutorials, 
        minLength: 0
    }).on('focus', function() { 
        $(this).keydown();
    });
});
```

Any suggestion how I can fix this?

Comment: why you are using `focus`? have you tried removing it. and also check for trailing commas in the array.

Comment: you don't need to handle focus event try this      http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/light/

Comment: Need to use focus to show all suggestions on the first click, before entering any information

Comment: If you want the user to see all available options upfront, then why are you using an autocomplete script in the first place? Makes little sense to me – I think you should rather use a `select` field or checkboxes/radio buttons, to let the user chose from the available options. (And if you need those to “look fancier”, then there’s enough scripts out there to accomplish that.)

Comment: It's the way the site is built, using asp.net textbox and I can't really change it as a couple of other things on the page depend on it as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
```

instead of

```
$(this).keydown();
```

Comment: This does work- However that way it doesn't work anymore that all the options are shown when the user clicks in the textfield

Comment: @MariaL can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I've used on focus so that all suggestions are shown on clicking in the searchbox and when I use the above code that doesn't work anymore. The autocomplete still works when you type something in, but if the user clicks in the search field it doesn't show all the suggestions

Comment: try using $(this).trigger('focus.autocomplete"), I haven't used it but givre it a try.

Comment: thanks, sorted it like this in the end :  .on('focus', function () { $(this).autocomplete('search', '');